# How prevent authorized users from responding to comments?

Tags: 7

How do I ensure that only administrators can reply to comments in sites such as content type? That is, if an authorized user views a node of the "content" type, he can leave a comment on it, but cannot reply to other comments, and a user with the administrator role can reply to all comments. How do I do this in Drupal?

Comment: check this out https://www.berramou.com/blog/drupal-8-how-prevent-log-inregister-post-comments-being-displayed-anonymous-users just change the conditions

Comment: I have 7 version of drupal